# How to convert Excel workbook to text (tab delimited)?

Tags: excel, text, tabs, delimited

I follow the instruction for converting Excel workbook to text (tab delimited), so it can be readable by R. However it does not work. The output are saved as text (tab delimited) when I check the properties. But when I open the file, nothing has changed. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: do you want to use Excel save as feature to convert workbook to text? have you tried unicode text option?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a tab delimited file with **Excel**, it will show in the Excel grid.

Open the tab delimited file with a text editor like Notepad.